# ServerVersion threw an exception of type System.InvalidOperationException (vb.net)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Using a new machine I setup my environment and code that used to work no longer seems to work. I can't seem to `open()` a connection to my database.

```
Public Shared Function GetDataSet(ByVal CmndText As String,
                                  Optional ByVal NoWrite As Boolean = True,
                                  Optional isStoredProc As Boolean = False,
                                  Optional paramArr As IList(Of Object()) = Nothing,
                                Optional ByVal CSname As String = Nothing) As DataSet
    Dim dbPF As DbProviderFactory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory("System.Data.SqlClient")
    Dim cn As DbConnection = dbPF.CreateConnection
    ' Dim cn = New SqlConnection(cs()) ' Maybe this is the solution?
    _Err = ""

    Try
        If Not IsNothing(CSname) Then
            cn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings(CSname).ConnectionString
        ElseIf NoWrite Then
            cn.ConnectionString = csReadOnly()
        Else
            cn.ConnectionString = cs()
        End If
        Debug.WriteLine("clsDAta, cn: " & cn.ConnectionString)

        Dim dbc As DbCommand = dbPF.CreateCommand()
        dbc.CommandText = CmndText
        If isStoredProc Then dbc.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        If Not paramArr Is Nothing Then
            For Each param() As Object In paramArr
                Dim p As DbParameter = dbc.CreateParameter()
                p.ParameterName = param(0)
                'p.Value = param(1)
                p.DbType = CType(param(1), DbType)
                p.Value = dbVal(param(2))
                If Not IsNothing(param(3)) Then p.Size = CType(param(3), Integer)
                dbc.Parameters.Add(p)
            Next
        End If
        dbc.Connection = cn
        cn.Open() ' The code gets stuck here and after 10 seconds gives the InvalidOperationException 
        Dim adptr As DbDataAdapter = dbPF.CreateDataAdapter
        adptr.SelectCommand = dbc
        'adptr.SelectCommand = cn.CreateCommand
        'adptr.SelectCommand.CommandText = CmndText

        Dim ds As New DataSet
        adptr.Fill(ds)
        Return ds
    Catch ex As System.Exception
        _Err = ex.Message
        Return Nothing
    Finally
        cn.Close() ' Never connects always ends up here after calling open()
    End Try
End Function
```

I'm a bit at a loss here as I'm not sure how to proceed when code that used to work seems to no longer work. Any advice?

Comment: What is the authentication mode that you set in your new SQL server. Also, show your connection string

Comment: Please show the full information for the exception as well.

Comment: @F0r3v3r-A-N00b thank you for suggesting authentication mode! This helped me find the problem. It turns out it was actually the authentication mode on the new SQL server. When importing the database it turned my database users into, "sql user without login." So I ran `ALTER USER usr1 WITH LOGIN = login1;` and I'm now able to authenticate with my server. It was authentication all along!

Comment: @Kyle There should be a `cn.Dispose()` in the `Finally` section. The idea with *connection pooling*, which is what is used behind the scenes, is to create the connection, use it, and then dispose of it as soon as reasonable.

Comment: @Kyle FYI you may be able to post your own answer to the question to officially show what the resolution was to the problem.